# Python regular expression caret not working in multiline mode?

Tags: python, regex

The following piece of code does not match `foo2` in the multiline string:

```
re.match("^foo2", "foo1\nfoo2\nfoo3",re.MULTILINE)
```

Why is that? The documentation at [python.org](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MULTILINE) says in `MULTILINE` mode the Caret (`^`) also matches at the beginning of each line. I've also tried the "raw string" versions with `r` already, no joy. Using `findall` also does not help.
I'm obviously missing something here..

Comment: Use `search`. `match` anchor the match at the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`re.match`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.match) documentation:

> Note that even in `MULTILINE` mode, `re.match()` will only match at the beginning of the string and not at the beginning of each line.

You need to use `re.search`.

Comment: It is interesting that the original post does not contain this line from the documentation.

Comment: interesting? :-) just me being stupid not to read everything..
on the other way round, i think it'll help if the python docs mentioned that `match/search` issue at the explanation of `'$'`

Comment: Please do not call yourself names, we are just humans, we cannot remember everything. And a tip: when looking for something on SO, use tags in brackets and type some keyword of your problem: `[python][regex] match` - and it will surely give you a lot of interesting posts.